# Commercetools: How to get the type of product discount in a product?

Tags: commercetools

I use the commercetools JVM SDK and query ProductProjections, how do I get the information if an absolute product discount is applied?

Answer (score 1):

You need to expand the product discounts within the product prices to be able to get this information and then use an instanceof check with the ProductDiscountValue:

```
final ProductProjectionQuery query = ProductProjectionQuery.ofCurrent()
    //your query predicate
    .withPredicates(m -> m.id().is(productId))
    //asks to expand in every variant the discount information
    .withExpansionPaths(m -> m.allVariants().prices().discounted().discount());
final Optional<ProductProjection> loadedProduct = client().executeBlocking(query).head();
assertThat(loadedProduct.isPresent()).isTrue();
final ProductProjection productProjection = loadedProduct.get();
final List<Price> prices = productProjection.getMasterVariant().getPrices();
//here you need to have a look if it is the right price, maybe http://commercetools.github.io/commercetools-jvm-sdk/apidocs/io/sphere/sdk/products/search/ProductVariantFilterSearchModel.html#scopedPrice-- is a better option for you           
final Price price = prices.get(0);
assertThat(price.getDiscounted()).isNotNull();
final ProductDiscount referenceExpandedProductDiscount = price.getDiscounted().getDiscount().getObj();
assertThat(referenceExpandedProductDiscount).isNotNull();
assertThat(referenceExpandedProductDiscount.getValue() instanceof AbsoluteProductDiscountValue)
        .as("this is how you check if the discount is absolute")
        .isTrue();
```